# elasticsearch seach query by a chain order

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple queries, and I want the result filtered by query order.

For example, I want query 2 searched from query 1 results, and query 3 searched from query 2 results.
query 3 results should not go beyond query 1 results.

query3 ⊆ query2 ⊆ query1

```
| id       | document                       |  category  |  group |
| -------- | -----                          |  ---       |  ---   |
| 1        | I want better search           |  fruit     |  1     |
| 2        | I want to watch search movie   |  fruit     |  2     |
| 3        | search movie                   |  animal    |  1     |
```

query1 = Q("match", group="1")

query2 = Q("match", category="fruit")

query3 = Q("match", document="search")

What I want is only document 1 in the results.

It seems that the bool function will give equal weight for each query, for example, it will give results that have exact match for query3, query1 has no exact match or low relevance, which is not in order of query3 ⊆ query2 ⊆ query1.

This is my code:

```
    resp = es.search(index='test-vector-index', body={
        "query" : {      
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                { "match" : { "group" : "1" }},
                { "match": { "category": "fruit" } },
                { "match": { "document": "search" } },
          ]
        }

        }

        }
    )
```

They don't work the way I think, please help me how to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: best would be to provide your index mapping, sample docs and expected docs in JSON format, so that fellow SO users can reproduce the issue easily and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you really want.
If I understood well, you probably can use "filter" instead of a must.

After your update. A query like this should work for your exemple.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "document": "search"
        }}
      ], 
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category.keyword": "fruit"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "group": 1
          }
        }
  
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried filter, but it didn't give me the right result. my query3 didn't search from query1.

Comment: I will need more informations. Can you provide examples of data and result you want and don't want to understand the subtility of your needs

Comment: thank you for response, I edited my question, please take a look.